# Free actions on torus (reference request)

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry

I would like a reference for the following result:

> The torus $T^n$ does not admit a right free action by a compact connected semi-simple Lie group.

I also appreciate further generalizations since I want to include a small comment on a paper stating that:

> The torus $T^n$ does not admit a right (effective) action by a compact connected Lie group $G$ satisfying both i) A principal orbit has finite fundamental group; ii) $T^n$ carries a $G$-invariant metric such that $T^n/G$ has positive Ricci curvature.

Comment: Torus is the only connected Lie group that can act effectively on an aspherical manifold (e.g. a torus). This is proved in  [Conner, P. E.; Raymond, Frank
Actions of compact Lie groups on aspherical manifolds. 1970 Topology of Manifold].

Comment: @IgorBelegradek:  I suppose your definition of 'aspherical manifold' includes compactness, since the statement is not true for $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Come to think of it, it's not true for $S^1$, since $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ acts effectively on $S^1$.

Comment: @RobertBryant: Thank you, I mistakenly omitted the compactness assumption.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek:  But compactness of the manifold is not enough.  In fact, $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ acts effectively on $\mathbb{T}^n$ for all $n$.  I guess that the correct statement is that if a semi-simple Lie group acts effectively on a torus, then its maximal compact is abelian.

Comment: I should not write on MO so early in the morning. The statement is that if a compact connected Lie group acts on a closed aspherical manifold, then the group is a torus.

Comment: Here is another (perhaps more accessible) reference: [Compact group actions and maps into aspherical manifolds, Donnelly-Schultz, Topology 1982,https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938382900222].

Comment: I guess I had in mind a different result:  If $M^n$ is a closed $n$-manifold and there exist $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\in H^1(M,\mathbb{R})$ satisfying $\alpha_1\wedge\cdots\wedge\alpha_n\not=0$, then any compact connected Lie group that acts effectively on $M$ is abelian.  This applies to $\mathbb{T}^n$ of course, but also to the connected sum of $\mathbb{T}^n$ with any orientable connected, closed $n$-manifold.

Comment: Is this relevant? **[Bernstein:](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82197419.pdf)** If a compact connected semisimple Lie group $G$ acts on $X$,
$L$ is torsionfree and $f :X → K(L, 1)$ has $H^k(f ) = 0$, then $\dim X/G\geq k$.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments, these helped a lot.